# Как написать скрипт, чтобы при изменении разрешения скрипт включался\выключался

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Я хочу исползовать плагин jQuery mmenu, чтобы он начил работать при разрешении 1000px? вот только не знаю как написать скрипт. ПОмогите!

Comment: Пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь со справкой **[как задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Смотрит на ширину экрана при первой загрузке страницы
if($(window).width() < 1000) {
  $('.res').text('Ширина экрана < 1000 пикселей');
}
else {
  $('.res').text('Ширина экрана >= 1000 пикселей');
}

// Смотрит на ширину экрана при изменении расширении
$(window).resize(function() {
  if($(this).width() >= 1000) {
    $('.res').text('Ширина экрана < 1000 пикселей');
  }
  else {
    $('.res').text('Ширина экрана < 1000 пикселей');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="res"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var userWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
if (usertWidth <= 1000){
  "твой меню" == true;
}  else {
  "твой меню" == false;
}
```